# Помогите составить математическую формулу

Tags: математика

Надо что бы в зависимости от числа, предидущий результат увеличивался в два раза, например:

1 - 100
2 - 200
3 - 400
4 - 800

1,2,3,4 это числа как вы поняли, от которых нужно отталкиваться. Не судите строго за такой вопрос ,может быть элементарный, но с математикой вообще плохо дружу.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к ИТ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (var q=0; q<32; ++q) {
  console.log(100 * Math.pow(2, q))
}
```

Comment: А на php можно? :-D

Comment: Спасибо, уже нагуглил функцию pow

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(var q=100;q>0;console.log(q),q=q<<1);
```